# Windows 7 booting from old SSD

Tags: windows-7, boot

I built-up a new computer yesterday. Then, I installed my SSD on the old laptop. When I boot the system, I see windows logo, then it gives blue screen error which says check your disk for virus protection.

Error Code: 0x0000007B

Comment: You have put the old SSD into the new computer, right? But you have a whole different hardware, what shall it be good for?

Comment: This doesn't sound like a typical blue screen, can you post the error code? Or better a picture of the blue screen.

Comment: Yes I am wondering it also, is it for the hardware? What should I do?

Comment: Please perform at least the most basic of searches to show some research effort: http://superuser.com/search?q=0x0000007B

Comment: Is this a OEM Windows lic or retail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"If you were to transplant a hard drive previously installed with Windows from one PC into another PC, with a different motherboard and different hard drive controller, upon boot up you would likely get a BSOD with a 0x0000007B error like this"

[image]

Fixing the Hard Drive Controller when Transplanting Old Hard Drive into New Windows PC or Laptop - Fix Stop: 0x0000007B Error
We often have customers who love the way their Windows computer was configured with icons in certain places, a particular background, various free or paid programs installed, customized for them, and it was always painful to tell the customer that when their motherboard died, or they wanted to get a new computer, Windows would have to be re-installed, and all of that would have to be re-configured.

If you were to transplant a hard drive previously installed with Windows from one PC into another PC, with a different motherboard and different hard drive controller, upon boot up you would likely get a BSOD with a 0x0000007B error like this:

We sought out to find a way to transplant a used hard drive from one Windows computer into a brand new or used one, with a different motherboard and hard drive controller, without requiring a re-install of Windows, Applications and backup/recovery of all the data on the drive.

The method detailed below has been performed by us now dozens of times and works very well.  Please let us know if you attempt this procedure and have any questions about the process:

1. First obtain the UBCD4WIN boot CD utility from here:
   http://www.ubcd4win.com/downloads.htm
2. Follow the steps listed here to create the CD:
   http://www.ubcd4win.com/howto.htm
3. Install your old hard drive in the new computer.
4. Turn on computer and boot off the CD
5. Boot into the live environment
6. Go to Start > Programs> Registry Tools > FIX_hdc> Fix hard disk
   controller

[image]

Assuming your target Windows install is in C:\WINDOWS, push M on your keyboard.
Observe any further prompts and take action if necessary.
Reboot and remove the CD from the drive, you should now see your Windows OS booting up!
P.S. Assuming you are transplanting your old HDD into a new computer designed to run Windows 8, there are additional settings you need to change in the BIOS to enable this to work.

Source: 
http://praetas.blogspot.co.za/2013/07/fixing-hard-drive-controller-when.html

Comment: You should provide the method within your answer itself and of course provide a citation to the text you are quoting.  While I could edit the answer to include the information I feel is important, its not possible, for me to edit the information you feel is important.  *The link also does not work for me so there is that also.*

Comment: I find his answer to be perfectly valid and the link works. Why repeat the whole saga again if it is well explained in the link.

Comment: @whs as I understand your point, the reason it is important to include the information within a link, and not just the link itself, is because links, in the future, can stop working, or the site gets taken down or is closed. By including the information, this allows the OP, as well as others, see the answer within context of the question, in a known, working location.

Comment: Anything can change in the future. You worry too much.

Comment: @whs - That is the way things are done here. Quote the important aspect of the link. Give citation/credit to the actual author, provide link. You'll see if you hang around for a while. :)

Comment: This is a very useful link and it helped me a lot. I think you should make a copy-paste answer referencing the link for sake of information. We cannot  what will happen to link after many years.